# IF Condition || add Colum

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm new in python thanks to support as i have excel sheet with data mostly number that imported to python pandas .
column " Stuff time " which contain Number that  need to make (if function) in it
as if number is less than 14400 put 0 & if number >32400 put 32400 if not will put the exist number
ex:

below how it's done in excel that i want in python

```
1-33181 = ( if(33181 <14400,0 ,if  33181 >32400,32400 , 33181 ) = 33181
2-12000 = ( if(12000 <14400,0 ,if  12000 >32400,32400 , 12000 ) = 12000
```

i need to add column lets call it ( New Stuff time ) with cacaltion to be applied in raw more that 10000 rows

to put more clear view
condition in excel
if ( number )<1400 ,( Zero ) , if ( number )>32400 , 32400 , ( put the number that exist )

Answer (score 0):

Use [clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html#pandas.Series.clip)

```
df["new stuff time"] = df["stuff time"].clip(14400, 32400)
```

Comment: sorry it didn't work like i want . i suces to make new coulm , also if number >32400 it become 32400 . but it number is less that 14400 i need to input " Zero" , also if number is between ( 14400 & <32400 ) i need ti input the real number that in the cell